# C# String Extension Overloading

Tags: c#, overloading

I want to create an extension class for string that overloads the CompareTo method with the following:

```
    public static bool CompareTo(this string input, string compareValue, bool ignoreCase, bool removeExtraWhiteSpaces)
    {
        if (removeExtraWhiteSpaces)
        {
            input = input.RemoveNullsAndWhiteSpace(" ").Trim();
            compareValue = compareValue.RemoveNullsAndWhiteSpace(" ").Trim();
        }

        return (String.Compare(input, compareValue, ignoreCase)==0);
    }
```

However, when I attempt to use it in a normal class file like such:

```
currentAuthor.FirstName.CompareTo(previousAuthor.FirstName, true, true)
```

I am getting a compile error stating there is no overload for method CompareTo that takes 3 parameters.

Is my idea possible?

I know in normal classes I can overload until the son comes home.  Whether it is a static or non-static class.

Is there an exception for Extensions?  I have not really worked with them a lot.

Comment: Is the static class that your extension method defined in visible to your calling code? Are you missing a reference possibly?

Comment: If it is compile time error, then what preventing you from adding the error to the post ?

Comment: You are likely missing a `using <namespace>` at the top of your code.  Can't tell because you are not showing what your class is called let alone what namespace it is in.

Comment: Justin and Micky, I figured the same thing out as you guys types... I was missing the using to the class.  One other question is there a way you can set up a class to automatically be part of the string class with out having to use "using"  The current class is called StringExtensions.  Sorry for lack of code but it is company software that I work for...

    namespace Company.Shared.Extensions
    { 
        public static class StringExtensions

Comment: @Angela, You can kind of get that behaviour by using a tool such as Resharper that makes it incredibly easy to add those based on use.

Comment: You either have to have `using` or have it in the same or a namespace, or a namespace that is within that. Consider if you didn't; it would be horribly easy to end up with lots of conflicting overloads because there were conflicting extensions that were in different namespaces but visible anyway. While it can be a pain if you forget a using, it would be more of a pain if there was no "off switch". (That said, some IDEs will add the using for you if you select a given extension via intellisense).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!  I guess I was hoping to mimic javascript's declaration style in c#  I guess that is not the case.  That is okay.  I was just hoping I was missing something.  Using it is... And thanks again so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just confirmed by setting up a dotnetfiddle, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/62HhQ8. That what you're trying to do should work fine.

As others have mentioned, I think you just need to make sure the namespace your extension method was defined in is included in every file you're trying to call your CompareTo extension method from.

Otherwise, I see nothing wrong and have confirmed your method works.